# queue:work delay between failed jobs

Tags: laravel, queue, beanstalkd

I'm running Laravel 5.2

How can I define delay in seconds for retries on failed jobs? That is, if a job fails and my --tries option is setup to 3, 10 seconds delay between each of those 3 tries should take place.

My current config is this:

```
command=php /home/forge/default/artisan queue:work beanstalkd --daemon --timeout=60 --sleep=10 --quiet --tries=3 --delay=10 --queue="default"

autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/.forge/worker-41417.log
```

As you can see, I already have a --delay=10 but does not work. Failed jobs tries are executed one after the other.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually release it, that is described in the 5.2 documentation:

```
public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
{
    if (condition) {
        $this->release(10);
    }
}
```